# Reinterpret a vector of tuples that contain heterogenous types

Tags: julia

Julia's [reinterpret](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/arrays/#Base.reinterpret) function makes it convenient to reinterpret a block of memory (e.g. a vector of tuples into a matrix). However, I can only get this to work when all the data types in the tuple are of the same type.

For instance:

```
t = [(1, "a"), (2, "b"), (3, "c")]
reinterpret(reshape, Any, t)  # ERROR!!!
```

The error message is:

```
ERROR: ArgumentError: cannot reinterpret `Tuple{Int64, String}` as `Any`, type `Any` is not a bits type
```

I've also tried replacing `Any` with `Union{Int, String}`, but I still get an error. My target is to get a matrix like `[1 "a"; 2 "b"; 3 "c"]`:

```
3×2 Matrix{Any}:                                                                                                         
 1  "a"                                                                                                                  
 2  "b"                                                                                                                  
 3  "c"
```

Eventually, I would like to reinterpret vectors of more complex types, such as `Tuple{Matrix{Float64}, String, Vector{Int}}`.

Is there a way to get around this error?

Comment: Reinterpret is the wrong approach. You cannot interpret anything as `Any`. What rule would you apply to the data when reintetpreting? You have to reinterpret as a concrete type, and it must a bitstype too. Reinterpret as String can't work either. How many bits would you assign to each string? The String type doesn't tell you how long a string is. Even if you use Char, a Union does not specify the order of types or how many elements of each. You should just make a new array. Or maybe flatten followed by reshape could work (no guarantees).

Answer (score 1):

`reinterpret` works on bitstypes only.

You could do however:

```
julia> Vector{NTuple{2, Union{Int,String}}}(t)
3-element Vector{Tuple{Union{Int64, String}, Union{Int64, String}}}:
 (1, "a")
 (2, "b")
 (3, "c")
```